# SQL Parameter Result if Blank Returning all values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this code if in my parameters I use like '123' and nothing for the second one then I get every row returned because its matching the wilcards in the address2 with every row since its blank. Now how do I stop this from happening?

```
SELECT     AddressID, Address1, Address2
FROM         Address
WHERE     (Address1 LIKE '%' + @add1 + '%') OR
                      (Address2 LIKE '%' + @add2 + '%')
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nullif](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx). If the parameters to nullif is equal the result will be null and `like null` will not give any hits.

```
SELECT AddressID, Address1, Address2
FROM Address
WHERE (Address1 LIKE '%' + nullif(@add1, '') + '%') OR
      (Address2 LIKE '%' + nullif(@add2, '') + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty string will cause the results to come back, but null will not.

```
if ( @add2 = '' )
begin
    set @add2 = null
end

SELECT     AddressID, Address1, Address2
FROM         Address
WHERE     (Address1 LIKE '%' + @add1 + '%') OR
                      (Address2 LIKE '%' + @add2 + '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `REPLACE` function on top of `'%' + @add2 + '%'` (and for `@add1` probably) to replace `%%` with `''` or anything else that will return nothing.

For example:

```
SELECT     AddressID, Address1, Address2
FROM         Address
WHERE     (Address1 LIKE REPLACE('%' + @add1 + '%','%%', 'VoidInput')) OR
                      (Address2 LIKE REPLACE('%' + @add2 + '%','%%', 'VoidInput'))
```

This will match against 'VoidInput' for an empty parameter but otherwise match against original %input% string

Answer (score 0):

When @add2 is blank, it will be a positive match for everything in Address2.

Try this:

```
SELECT AddressID, Address1, Address2
FROM Address
WHERE ((@add1 <> '' and Address1 LIKE '%' + @add1 + '%') 
        OR (@add2 <> '' and Address2 LIKE '%' + @add2 + '%'))
```